# Open CD/DVD tray when connected via remote-desktop and no eject key?

Tags: high-sierra, remote-desktop, optical-drive, eject

I am connected to my headless (and keyboard less) Mac, which has a cd / dvd drive, via Remote Desktop.

If there is no disk in the drive, it doesn’t show up in Finder. How can I open the CD/DVD TRAY from a MacBook Pro without eject key?

When I connect a usb keyboard directly, I can eject via the eject key.

Comment: If there is no disc in the CD/DVD drive then it will not appear under **Devices** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder**!

Comment: @user3439894 Makes sense. But is there a way of opening the tray, apart from the keyboard (eject key) or the command line?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from the Terminal by entering the following command:

```
drutil tray eject
```

Comment: This works - but isn't there a keyboard shortcut via remote-desktop I could use?

Comment: You need to create a service then add your desired keyboard shortcut.